# Set Adapter for Fragment's ListView from Parent

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

So basically a Fragment is placed inside an Activity via a ViewPager and I'm trying to populate a ListView which is inside the Fragment by inflating it from the Parent Activity. However, the items don't get populated and no error is thrown.

> The data should be populated from the activity
>
> The listview is in the fragment

Here's my code:

**Activity**:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView peopleList;
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        //Inflate the Fragment to a new View Object
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vii = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_people_tab, null);
        //Initialise the ListView with the Fragment's listview
        peopleList = (ListView) vii.findViewById(R.id.searchpeople_list);
        
        data.add("1");         
        data.add("2");     

        PopulateResults();
}

private void PopulateResults() {
        //populate the fragment's listview with the data generated by the parent activity
        SearchPeopleResultsAdapter adapter = new SearchPeopleResultsAdapter(SearchActivity.this,data);
        peopleList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I simply want to populate a listview which is in the fragment with the values generated by the parent activity. How do I get this done folks?

**EDIT:**

So basically, the ACTIVITY has an EditText and below that I have a ViewPager with two Fragments. The first Fragment has a ListView. 'On Text changed' I need to populate the ListView with the data. This is for a Search functionality :)

Comment: Why can't you initialize the ListView from inside the Fragment?

From what I understood, you should retrieve the Fragment instance from within the ViewPager adapter.

Comment: @LeoFarage Edited the question with more information :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways you can achieve the ListView's initialization.

**First**: Initialize it from within your Fragment `onCreateView` as the ListView belongs to the Fragment and it makes sense to let it handle this.

**Second**: Add your data into a `Bundle` and add it to the Fragment using `setArguments()` method from Fragment, then inside the `onCreate()` retrieve the `Bundle` and the data you attached.

**Third**: Save a list of your Fragments, saving them from within the `getItem()` inside your `FragmentPagerAdapter`. And when you need to initialize/update the ListView adapter you can retrieve the `Fragment` and call a method created by you to initialize/update the ListView.

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Let's say you have a `TextView` and on its `TextWatcher#afterTextChanged()` method you do something like:

```
// This adapter should be your custom adapter -- extending FragmentPagerAdapter
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) mViewPagerAdapter.getFragment(targetFragmentPostion);
fragment.addNewData(yourNewData);
```

Inside `YourFragment#addNewData(...)` method you could have something like:

```
mListOfData.add(newData);
mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I'm assuming you where successful in initializing your ListView, so this edited content is for updating its content.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh perhaps.. is it possible to just send the Data from the Activity to the Fragment dynamically? Like, as soon as text is changed in the EditText the data is passed to the Fragment. That way I can easily populate it. How can I pass the data, mate?

Comment: Yes, of course. You just have to retrieve the Fragment instance and call your "setData" (you create this method) method. Make sure to cast the retrieved retrieved Fragment to your Fragment type (class you extended from Fragment).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what the actual implementation on your side without Fragment code, but the way you described its not going to work, as you are inflating a fragments's view in `onCreate()` of Activity by inflating that view xml but the actual fragment view will be rendered on `onCreateView()` of fragment.

So in your case, you have to pass your adapter data from Activity to Fragment via bundle or any other method and just populate your view inside `onCreateView()` of Fragment.

in simple words, as per your current implementation both views are different so it won't effect or update your Fragment view. The actual Fragment view is created by `onCreateView(`) method only (what you seen on your device screen).